# ORACLE QUERY to pass date as variable in TOAD

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I'm new to oracle and trying to run a simple query to pass date dynamically

```
DEFINE startdate = TO_DATE(select TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS( max(nav_last_calc_dt) ,-1))+1) from tb);

DEFINE enddate = TO_DATE(select TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(max(nav_last_calc_dt),0)))  from tb);

begin
select Count(1)
FROM  tb
WHERE  DATE BETWEEN &startdate  AND  &enddate;
 
end;
```

I received the below error when executing using script (F5), TOAD script runner.

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 78:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

But when using SQL PLUS , it returned 7 as result. So I'm confused.

Comment: That code isn't going to work in SQL\*Plus either. Was the '7' you got actually a result, or just the next-line number prompt? (If it just shows 7 as the final thing you can see, type a slash (`/`) and hit return...) Why do you want to use define for this?

Answer (score 3):

SQL*Plus isn't returning 7 as the result; you haven't completed the anonymous PL/SQL block, so it is showing you 7 as the next line number (as 'begin' is line 1 and 'end;' is line 6, and is waiting for input. If you enter a slash and hit return it will then execute the block; which will throw the same ORA-00936 error.

In both clients the problem is the `DATE` keyword - it's expecting that to be the start of a date literal, and doesn't see the rest of the literal value as it expects. That should be a column name, presumably:

```
WHERE nav_last_calc_dt DATE BETWEEN &startdate  AND  &enddate;
```

But the block will still fail, possibly for different reasons in the two clients; in SQL*Plus it will still get ORA-00936 because the defined value ends at the first space (which you can fix by enclosing in double quotes), and Toad may throw that error or complain that your select has no 'into' clause. (Or it might do something else; SQL Developer against 12cR1 is throwing an internal error.) The outer `TO_DATE` in your defined expressions is also not ideal - it will implicitly convert the date you have to a string and then convert that string back again to a real date, both using your session NLS settings; which might work, but isn't needed.

It's not clear why you are using PL/SQL there, or really why you are using a substitution variable - it's not really dynamic, it just makes the final statement a bit more obscure.

The date calculation also seems a bit complicated. It looks like you're trying to count rows from the last month with any data; and you're finding the first day of that month using `add_months` and `last_day` - which could be done more simply just by truncating the maximum date using the 'MM' date component:

```
select count(*)
from tb
where nav_last_calc_dt >= (select trunc(max(nav_last_calc_dt), 'MM') from tb)
```

Assuming the column used for the filter is `nav_last_calc_dt, and not some other column, you don't need an upper bound - you know the maximum date is in that month, so it *has* to be within the month.

If if was another column, with later dates, and you used `between` then you would exclude any values after midnight on the last day of that month. It's safer to use a full month range:

```
select count(*)
from tb
where some_date >= (select trunc(max(nav_last_calc_dt), 'MM') from tb)
and some_date < (select add_months(trunc(max(nav_last_calc_dt), 'MM'), 1) from tb)
```

which would find all values at or after midnight on the first day of the target month, and before midnight on the first day of the following month.

It might then be worth getting the maximum date once, but you could do that in a CTE or an inline view rather than via `define`, which wouldn't actually save you anything the way you are trying to use it - since both defined queries would be substituted into the query/block before it's executed.

Comment: 1) Now I understand 7 as the next line number.  2) Sorry, my bad, the DATE was actualy created_date ..I wrote it as DATE for posting online purpose.  3) My requirement is, I want to use 2 variables for start and end date for my very long script and use it. Hence I simplified it. Kindly suggest

Comment: To use the same values repeatedly in multiple separate queries in a script; or just within a single query; or within a single PL/SQL block? Assuming you mean across multiple queries, you can use substitution variables, or bind variables, but you would end up converting string to dates a lot.

Comment: select Count(1) FROM  tb WHERE  CREATE_DATE BETWEEN &startdate  AND  &enddate;

Pls help me run this query with help of variables as above in oracle. in SQL server this is very simple. Thanks in Advance